# Error installing starting a project with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to start a new project using gruntjs.

I have this project structure:

```
grunt-test (dir)
  |_ index.html
  |_ package.json
  |_ Gruntfile.js
  |_ assets (dir)
    |_ _js (dir)
      |_ scripts.js
    |_ _sass (dir)
      |_ style.sass
```

I have nodejs and grunt installed.

So, when I go to project's folder and use this command line on terminal: `npm install grunt --save-dev`

It returns me all those errors:

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt-test/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt-test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt-test/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/grunt-test/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've been trying to install it for a while and I haven't had any success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm following all the instructions on gruntjs docs. Can someone help me?

Comment: could you show us your package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `package.json` is not a valid `JSON`. Instead of typing in commands, you can add these as `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file and then use `npm install` which will install packages from the `package.json` file. You can use the below.

```
{
    "name": "Project Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "0.4.4",
        "grunt-cli": "0.1.13"
    }
}
```

Run `npm install grunt-cli -g` if `grunt` is not found message gets displayed.

Comment: So what should I do? Always when I create a new project I have to create and add some lines on package.json before using terminal?

Comment: My bad. Please add quotes for json props. Updated the answer.

Comment: The image look same as the previous one. Are you sure the error is the same?

Comment: The previous one was returns it: npm ERR! Unexpected token '.. Now its returning this: npm ERR! Unexpected token '

Comment: You need the whole string to be in double quotes. Who would have known that! Just use the updated file. It works. Tested in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, strings are enclosed into single quotes ('), it makes it a non-valid JSON data. JSON expects strings to be enclosed into double quotes (").